# How do I wrap an exe with a bat file so I can set environmental variables and still pass arguments?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an exe that needs the `PYTHONHOME` environemental variable to be set. It also takes some command line arguments. Is there a way to make a batch file (or even a shortcut?) that will set an environemental variable and then pass the command line arguments on to the exe?

Answer (score 0):

Aha it is like this:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\yotta\python
arm-none-eabi-gdb-py %*
```

Comment: Or in a shortcut `cmd /c set PYTHONHOME=C:\yotta\python & 
arm-none-eabi-gdb-py` but this won't do arguments.